# mongodb: reduce function not action when only one result is there

Tags: mongodb

I  need to do the weighted average.

Did the coding as below

```
db.runCommand(
{ mapreduce : "<collecton>" ,
map: function ()
{
emit ({nkey: this.nkey}, {price: this.tags["31"], qty: this.tags["32"]});
},
reduce: function(key, vals)
{
var ret = {wavg:0};
var mul1 = 0.0;
var sum1 = 0.0;
for (var i=0;i<vals.length;i++)
{ mul1 += vals[i].price * vals[i].qty;
  sum1 += vals[i].qty;
}
ret.wavg = mul1/sum1;
return ret;
},
out: 'res2', verbose: true
}
);

> db.res2.find()
{ "_id" : { "nkey" : "key1" }, "value" : { "wavg" : 311.7647058823529 } }
{ "_id" : { "nkey" : "ke2" }, "value" : { "wavg" : 585.7142857142857 } }
{ "_id" : { "nkey" : "key3" }, "value" : { "price" : 1000, "qty" : 110 } }
{ "_id" : { "nkey" : "key4" }, "value" : { "wavg" : 825 } }
```

If you notice, in the final reducer output(third row), it dint actually go thru the reduce functionality. The key occur only once, hence one result will be emitted. But I still want the reduce function to be acting on that to get the weighted average. I can't just go ahead with price and qty wherever I have only one occurence of the key, where I need weighted average for that key also.

Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: use the finalize function instead

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially how mapReduce works in that the reducer is never called when you only have one result. But you can always alter such results with a [**`finalize`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#mapreduce-finalize-cmd) stage:

```js
db.runCommand({ 
    "mapreduce" : "<collecton>" ,
    "map": function () {
        emit (
            { "nkey": this.nkey}, 
            { "price": this.tags["31"], qty: this.tags["32"]}
        );
    },
    "reduce": function(key, vals) {
        var ret = { "wavg": 0 };
        var mul1 = 0.0;
        var sum1 = 0.0;

        for ( var i=0; i<vals.length; i++ ) { 
            mul1 += vals[i].price * vals[i].qty;
            sum1 += vals[i].qty;
        }

        ret.wavg = mul1/sum1;
        return ret;
    },
    "finalize": function(key,value) {
        if (value.hasOwnProperty("price") {
           value.wavg = value.price;
           delete value["price"];
        }

        return value;
    },
    "out": 'res2', 
    "verbose": true
});
```

Or otherwise alternately just sum your keys in the `reduce` stage and do all the division in the `finalize` stage if that suits you thinking better. But then you would need to do your "multiplication" part in the "mapper" for that to work.

Comment: It worked and thanks. But in the Hadoop map reduce, the reduce will run even when there is only one row

Comment: @user3639648 Not too sure about that, but the general spec of mapReduce is to combine multiple emissions of the same key and where that key has only one value then there should be nothing for the reducer to do. That is at least the definition in the original Google papers so this is exactly what the MongoDB implementation does. This is covered in the manual page as referenced by the link given.